# How can the crawling be improved for single page applications build with Angular4 and VueJS

Tags: angular, vue.js, seo, single-page-application

I have my single page application built with Angular and Vue. Pre-rendred HTML pages can improve the crawling. Is there any other steps i can take to make my page search engine optimized?

Comment: To make static HTML pages, npm package "angular-statisfy" can be used

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.